# Как правильно обрабатывать внешние зависимости при сборке npm библиотеки

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, vite, package.json

Делаю библиотеку ( ui компонент react, scss, но не суть  ) в частности интересует вопрос как правильно обрабатывать при сборке внешние зависимости, которые указаны в блоке

```
"dependencies": {
    "@uiw/react-md-editor": "^3.23.3",
    "event-target-shim": "^6.0.2",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.7.2",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.0"
  },
```

c «"peerDependencies"» вроде как все понятно, при сборке они в конечный бандл не попадают а просто остается импорт либы, которая уже буддет браться из приложения потребителя этой либы и сборка ее будет леажать на соввести сборщика этого конечного приложения потребителя

А вот с «dependencies» не совсем понятно, т.к. vite(lib mod) по умолчанию такие зависимости кидает в бандл, а rullup отдельно без vite такие зависимости обрабатывает аналогично peerDependencies
чет я вот не могу понять как все таки надо dependencies бандлить  что бы не раздувать бандл конечного приложения?

Answer (score 0):

При сборке npm библиотеки важно правильно обрабатывать внешние зависимости из блока "**dependencies**", чтобы избежать раздувания размера конечного бандла приложения, которое будет использовать твою библиотеку.

Если ты используешь инструменты сборки типа Vite или Rollup, есть несколько подходов, которые можно применить.

External: Внешние зависимости могут быть объявлены как внешние модули и не включаться в итоготый бандл. Вместо этого, они ожидаются во время тыполнения от приложения-потребителя. В Vite это можно настроить с помощью параметра rollupOptions.external в файле vite.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  rollupOptions: {
    external: ['@uiw/react-md-editor', 'event-target-shim', 'normalize.css', 'react-select', 'react-toastify'],
  },
};
```

Peer Dependency: Если ты хочешь, чтобы зависимости были доступны для использования во время разработки и компиляции твоей библиотеки, но не включались в конечный бандл, ты можешь указать их как peerDependencies. Это гарантирует, что эти зависимости уже установлены в приложении-потребителе, которое будет использовать библиотеку. В этом случае, импорты зависимостей в твой библиотеке останутся, но сборка приложения-потребителя будет отвечать за их обработку.

Оптимизация и код-сплиттинг: ты также можешь использовать оптимизацию и код-сплиттинг, предоставляемые инструментами сборки, чтобы сократить размер бандла. Например, в Vite настроить динамический импорт для библиотеки, чтобы она была загружена только по требованию. Это поможет уменьшить размер инициального бандла и улучшить производительность приложения. Вот пример:

```
import('@uiw/react-md-editor').then((module) => {
  // Используйте модуль из @uiw/react-md-editor
});
```